# Can't run "git" without sudo on OS X

Tags: macos, permissions, git

I have an administrator account on my OS X Lion 10.7.2. I have installed a few applications through this account, but I am not able to run them without sudo. For example, I installed git and I cannot just simply run `git` from the terminal as I get

> -bash: git: command not found

Instead I need to run `sudo git`.

I have similar issues with other applications. Another one that is not working is MacFusion.app that tries to use `/Applications/Macfusion.app/Contents/PlugIns/sshfs.mfplugin/Contents/Resources/sshfs-static`. I tried running `sshfs-static` from the terminal, but once again I had to sudo to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I used git-osx-installer that I downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3 . I checked my PATH and /usr/local/git/bin is in it.

Comment: I checked my path without `sudo`. I did `echo $PATH`

Comment: Add `PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.bash_profile` and check that the `git` binary file has correct permissions (execute set).

Comment: I just found out that I cannot even `ls /usr/local` without sudo. How do I fix that? All the directories there have been set to `root` as user and `wheel` as group.

Comment: Then try `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`. It's not a system folder anyway, so it's better to keep it owned by you.

Comment: That solved everything. Who are usually default owner and group for /usr/local ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/usr/local` is not used on a default installation of OS X and typically is owned by your user, since you will create it and populate it. The popular package manager [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) will  set the permissions and use it without ever needing root permissions.

If it's owned by `root`, and missing execute/read permissions for your user, then the commands in `/usr/local/bin` (or `/usr/local/git/bin`) will only work when called with `sudo`.

To fix this, take ownership of `/usr/local` again:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

As for why this happened, I can only guess that the git-osx-installer reset the permissions of `/usr/local` to something more restrictive. Some bug reports mention that.

Comment: can you please explain what does $(whoami) mean?

Comment: @SamirSabri The `whoami` command returns your username. When you wrap a command in `$()`, its output is replaced on the commandline. This is called [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). Thus, for example, when I type `echo $(whoami)`, it runs `echo slhck`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/402816/659669), which suggests:

> To fix this, take ownership of /usr/local again:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
> ```

I had to run the following two lines in the terminal to get Git working without sudo:

```
echo "PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:\$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Source: [Installing git on OSX 10.8 without Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197945/installing-git-on-osx-10-8-without-xcode)

Hope this helps.